# Combining Face Recognition with Face Emotion recognizer from webcam

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have a task where my job is to code a face recognizer which then analyses the pictures, compares it to a live webcam footage and displays the name of the person aswell as the dominant emotion.
What i currently have is this code snippet i took from this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/face-detection-using-python-and-opencv-with-webcam/ and that i modified to this:

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from deepface import DeepFace
size = 4
haar_file = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
datasets = 'datasets'
 
# Part 1: Create fisherRecognizer
print('Recognizing Face Please Be in sufficient Lights...')
 
# Create a list of images and a list of corresponding names
(images, labels, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0)
for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(datasets):
    for subdir in dirs:
        names[id] = subdir
        subjectpath = os.path.join(datasets, subdir)
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath):
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename
            label = id
            images.append(cv2.imread(path, 0))
            labels.append(int(label))
        id += 1
(width, height) = (130, 100)
 
# Create a Numpy array from the two lists above
(images, labels) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, labels]]
 
# OpenCV trains a model from the images
# NOTE FOR OpenCV2: remove '.face'
model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
model.train(images, labels)
 
# Part 2: Use fisherRecognizer on camera stream
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file)
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
emotion_dict = {
    0: 'Surprise',
    1: 'Happy', 
    2: 'Disgust',
    3: 'Anger',
    4: 'Sadness',
    5: 'Fear',
    6: 'Contempt'
}
while True:
    (_, im) = webcam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height))
        # Try to recognize the face
        prediction = model.predict(face_resize)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)
        max_index = np.argmax(prediction[0])
        emotions = ('angry', 'disgust', 'fear', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise', 'neutral')
        predicted_emotion = emotions[max_index]
        cv2.putText(im, predicted_emotion, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if prediction[1]<500:
           cv2.putText(im, '% s - %.0f' %
(names[prediction[0]], prediction[1]), (x-10, y-10),
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0))
           
        else:
          cv2.putText(im, 'not recognized',
(x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0))
 
    cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im)
     
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

however, when i try to run it, it only says that my emotion is angry, even though i am smiling or frowning. Does anyone have a suggestion to why this is? I'm eager to figure it out so comments are greatly appreciated

Comment: debug _your code_. you use it, now it's yours. look at `prediction`. what values do you see? -- it uses the `LBPHFaceRecognizer` to distinguish faces. did you even train it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work now by using fer (pip install fer).